# Relationship of unique lock, mutex and condition variable in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, condition-variable

Hello I have the following code:

```
// condition_variable example
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

void print_id (int id) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  while (!ready) cv.wait(lock);
  // ...
  std::cout << "thread " << id << '\n';
}

void go() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  ready = true;
  cv.notify_all();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread threads[10];
  // spawn 10 threads:
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    threads[i] = std::thread(print_id,i);

  std::cout << "10 threads ready to race...\n";
  //go();                       // go!

  for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
  std::cout << "Finished!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If I remove the comment on the function call go() inside main, I get the following output:

```
10 threads ready to race...
thread 0
thread 8
thread 1
thread 2
thread 4
thread 5
thread 3
thread 6
thread 7
thread 9
Finished!
```

I fully understand some of the flow on why I am getting this output. However, I do not understand why I cannot print "10 threads ready to race..." if I comment out go() function call inside main. If I understand it correctly, I did not invoke notify_all() by not calling go() so threads will not wake up but why is it that the print function "10 threads ready to race..." didn't get invoked as well?

And also, kindly explain why i need to call std::unique_lock lock(mtx); inside go() function. Thank you guys!

BTW just for citation, I got this example at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/

Comment: So you're not seeing the line "10 threads ready to race..." in the output, am I understanding this correctly? I tried your code and it printed it, so it has probably something to do with stream flushing. Try using `std::cout << "10 threads ready to race..." << std::endl;` instead.

Comment: Yes! using std::endl works! but what is happening there? why didn't it print it when std::endl was not used?

Comment: `stdout` is a buffered stream, so characters will be written into a buffer and when this buffer is full it will be flushed and written onto the terminal. `std::endl` appends a '\n' to the stream and automatically flushes the buffer.

Comment: And also can you explain the significance of std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx); inside go() function? I tried to delete it and uncomment call to go() function. With or without std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx); yields same result

Comment: Locking a mutex prevents other threads from obtaining the ownership of the current context. This is usually used on objects or variables which are shared by multiple threads to prevent race conditions. In your case however this is just used to make the thread sleep until `notify_all()` is called.

Comment: So this has no significant effect right? the thread is already sleeping before notify_all() is called because i used cv.wait() on it. So I can delete mutex lock inside go()?

Comment: No, because you're using the mutex object to actually create the `unique_lock`which is then used to enable you to wait for the condition variable. I'm not that well elaborated using threads in C++ so I would recommend reading a good book on that topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard output is buffered. That means that each output operation is not separately sent to the parent process, but instead they are gathered in memory and sent in bulk. This is done to minimize the overhead of system call / inter process communication - or whatever the output requires.

When the buffer is filled, it will be flushed, and only when it is flushed do you see any output. Apparently `10 threads ready to race...` was not enough to fill the buffer.

The buffer is flushed also when the program ends, or when standard input is accessed or if you request explicitly, using `std::flush` or `std::endl`.

When your program waits indefinitely for other threads (in a deadlock), it will never reach the point where the buffer is filled further and eventually flushed.

Comment: Thank you. This is very good answer. I have a follow up question. When i change cv.notify_all() to cv.notify_one(). Will I reach a deadlock? I am pretty sure that I will reach a deadlock, however, I do not understand why several threads got woken up instead of just exactly one by using cv.notify_one()

Comment: @Redis1001 did you test it?

Comment: Yes.. I tested it http://fiddle.jyt.io/ sometimes i get only one thread woken up. but sometimes i get three threads woken up using cv.notify_one()

Comment: @Redis1001 so, if all of the threads were not woken up in all of your attempts, would you say that the program is guaranteed to finish eventually or not?

Comment: I think it will reach deadlock and the program will not finish.. However, I do not understand why there are times where 3 threads get woken up.

Comment: @Redis1001 could be spurious wakeups.